# Finding Field Keys and Values with InfluxDB Java Client

Tags: java, influxdb

Using the [InfluxDB Java client](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java) to communicate w/ my InfluxDB instance from a Java app.

I'm trying to accomplish something that doesn't appear to be documented anywhere inside the project. For a particular measurement, I need to list its latest (timestamp-wise) field key(s) and their values without knowing what they are called!

Hence let's say I have a measurement called `FizzBuzz`:

```
> SHOW measurements
name: measurements
name
----
FizzBuzz
```

I believe `ORDER BY ASC` is InfluxDb's default meaning the last/latest measurement data is always the last to come back in the query by default. So I *think* I'm looking to run something like this from Java:

```
SELECT * FROM FizzBuzz ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1;
```

However my app will *not know* what the field key(s) on that returned result will be, and so I need a way (via the API) to inspect the record that is return and obtain the name of any field keys (so I can save them as strings) and obtain their respective values (which I can safely assume can be cast to `BigDecimals`).

My best attempt thus far:

```
Query query = new Query("SELECT * FROM FizzBuzz ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1", "my-app-db");
QueryResult queryResult = connection.query(query);

for(Result result : queryResult.getResults()) {
    for(Series series : result.getSeries()) {
        List<String> cols = series.getColumns();

        // But how to tell whats a field vs whats a tag?!
    }
}
```

However this doesn't allow me to discern which columns are fields vs. which ones are just tags...any ideas?

Comment: In general `show tag keys from FizzBuzz` and `show field keys from FizzBuzz` queries can tell you tag names and (field_name, field_type) information about measurement scheme. This can be used to distinguish tags and fields in select query result.

Comment: Thanks @YuriLachin (+1) but thats only via the `influx` CLI tool, do you know if its possible to run that command from the InfluxDB Java library somehow?

Comment: Not familiar with influx java client, but I'm 99% sure that you can just use `Query query = new Query("SHOW TAG KEYS FROM FizzBuzz", "my-app-db")` and inspect the result (see comment for `describeDatabases()` in https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/influxdb/InfluxDB.java).

Comment: Yep @YuriLachin [I think you're right](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java/blob/74c3febd50b165a6b4fd4d1c2a0710956a306564/src/main/java/org/influxdb/impl/InfluxDBImpl.java#L712). I'll play around with this and let you know either way, thanks for the nudge here!